# EJB cannot be found

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, ejb

I'm trying to use JavaBeans or the first time and I'm getting the following 
error:

> javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: DemoEJB
>
> javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for
>   'java:global/DemoEJB/ContenedorEJB/BeanStateful!beanssesion.BeanStatefulLocal'
>   in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory

I'm using NetBeans with glassfish 4.1 server.
The application is really simple, I have an Enterprise application project where I link an EJB Module (called ContenedorEJB) and a Client (which is a Servlet).

This is the projects structure:

- ClienteWeb

  - Source Packages

    -servlets

    -ServletEJB.java
- ContenedorEJB

  -Source Packages

  - beanssesion

    - BeanStateful.java
    - BeanStatefulLocal.java
- DemoEJB

  -Java EE Modules

  - ContenedorEJB.jar
  - ClienteEJB.war

The servlet code is as follows bellow. The only thing I do it's look up the sessionBean,

```
c.lookup("java:global/DemoEJB/ContenedorEJB/BeanStateful!beanssesion.BeanStatefulLocal");
```

save it, and then use the implemented methods getValor and setValor just to see if the values I send to the EJB Module are saved. But it gets lost because it can't find the BeanStateful even though it's there.

```
package servlets;

import beanssesion.BeanStatefulLocal;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class ServletEJB extends HttpServlet {

    BeanStatefulLocal beanStateful = lookupBeanStatefulLocal();

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {

            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet ServletEJB</title>");            
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");

            out.println("Enviamos un valor al EJB Stateful: ");
            beanStateful.setValor("Valor desde Servlet");
            out.println("Valor devuelto " + beanStateful.getValor());

            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

    private BeanStatefulLocal lookupBeanStatefulLocal() {
        try {
            Context c = new InitialContext();
            return (BeanStatefulLocal) c.lookup("java:global/DemoEJB/ContenedorEJB/BeanStateful!beanssesion.BeanStatefulLocal");
        } catch (NamingException ne) {
            Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "exception caught", ne);
            throw new RuntimeException(ne);
        }
    }   
}
```

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

As you are using GlassFish 4.1 you will find life simpler if you put all of your classes (including EJBs) in your web module for the time being.

Secondly you rarely need to use explicit JNDI lookups anymore; use injection instead:

```
public class ServletEJB extends HttpServlet {

    @javax.ejb.EJB
    BeanStatefulLocal beanStateful;

    ...
}
```

BUT, there is a big problem with using stateful session beans like this. This servlet instance will be shared with **all** clients and so will the EJB that you are injecting/looking up. This will lead to serious concurrency issues.

Comment: Yep, I was following an example and trying both Stateful and Stateless session beans. I tried what you suggested but it still can't find the ejb bean: StandardWrapperValve[ServletEJB]: Servlet.service() for servlet ServletEJB threw exception
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: beanssesion/BeanStatefulLocal